# HTML and PHP in js

Tags: javascript, php, html

Bellow is my php function which grabs profile image thumb of my visitor

```
<?php echo voip_profile_image($visitorid,'thumb'); ?>
```

problem is that *$visitorid* is stored in JS under *sRemoteid* parameter.bellow with my very poor knowledge of JS i came up with the script which of course i am not able to make work:

```
$('.incoming-call-alert .photoarea').html('<img src="<?php echo voip_profile_image("'+sRemoteid+'","thumb"); ?>" class="client-profile-image-thumb">');
```

expected result should look like this, basically all i need to do is put visitorid to my html script from JS. because it is not stored nor there is any other option to store it anywhere else than JS file.

```
<div class="incoming-call-alert">
  <div class="photoarea">
    <img src="<?php echo voip_profile_image(visitorid,'thumb'); ?>" class="client-profile-image-thumb">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have those asterisks in your actual code? Probably not, right? Please show your actual code.

Comment: You can't go backward, look there is code flow:-

Comment: Is the jQuery line inline code in a PHP file? Or is it part of a JS file?

Comment: OP: you keep editing your question but your still have asterisks in your code, which I assume shouldn't actually be in there. Would you please read and react to the comments you're getting?

Comment: If you want to get info from the server, you need your javascript to make an HTTP request back to the server to get that data. Technically you can have some PHP write some values into javascript but you can't write executable code, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where is `sRemoteid` coming from?

Comment: @Chris G, it is js file. and yes the code is for asterisk softphone using sipml5

Comment: That is a funny coincidence, but I'm talking about the `*` symbols in your code. Please remove those, you cannot make variables bold inside code.

Comment: @Chris G, very strange seems that stackoverflow added ** symbols somehow,should be ("'+sRemoteNumber+'","thumb")

Comment: *"it is js file"* - JS files can't run PHP directives. Look at your HTML source and you'll literally see your PHP *as* code.

Comment: (Edited, as per your edit): *"should look like this `... (visitorid,'thumb') ....`"* - The `visitorid` here, would be treated as a constant, and [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have thrown you an error about it, once set to run under a PHP environment. So no; it should *not* look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have something like this in one of your scripts:

```
var sRemoteid = 123;
```

This variable only exists in the browser's memory, long after the PHP code on the server ran and created the HTML. If you want to do something on the server based on a JS variable, you have to make a new request to the server. You can do this without navigating to a page or sending a form if you use AJAX. jQuery has `$.ajax` and others, there's also `fetch()`.

However, since this is about showing an image, it's much more sensible here to request the image directly, without a previous AJAX call for the URL. Create a PHP endpoint that serves the image:

```
<?php
$imageid = $_GET['id'];
$thumbnail = /* logic here to find path to file */
// load image file
$png = imagecreatefrompng($thumbnail);
// serve image file
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Now use jQuery to create an `<img>` and set its source using the new PHP file's URL, passing along the `id`:

```
var $img = $("<img>").addClass("client-profile-image-thumb"); // use proper jQuery to create <img>
$img.attr("src", "/client_profile_thumb.php?id=" + sRemoteid); // set src using endpoint URL
$('.incoming-call-alert .photoarea').append($img);
```

Comment: Thank you for the guide yes i use jQuery, if i understand correctly from your comments and this guide there is possibility to pass variable to my php file from js file ? can you kindly advise in more details how do i perform that ?

Comment: 1. use JS to add `<img src="/client_profile_thumb.php?id=123">` to your page 2. in the PHP file, grab the id and serve the image. Which details exactly do you need? You do know how to process GET parameters in PHP, right?

Comment: Ok it is clear now, i thought i could pass the value without creating another file. i will try to implement above to my code.

Comment: I don't know how the rest of your PHP is set up, but you don't need another file; you could add that PHP code to an existing file in theory.

Answer (score 1):

Code flow like below

First PHP is executed, and return the HTML page
HTML is sent to the browser
and the browser will then execute the javascript.

you can't break the flow.

If you want to change anything via Javascript, then you have to get data from php via ajax and then change the dom.

via ajax you should execute the `voip_profile_image($visitorid,'thumb');` by sending the `sRemoteid` variable in `POST` or `GET`, and then change the `img` dom via js

Comment: This is basically true, but what OP is trying will work if they a) fix the syntax b) that jQuery line is in a PHP file.

Comment: This is more fit as a comment, IMHO.

Comment: He is trying to change the DOM via JS, and adding PHP in it. please let me know how will that php execute. @ChrisG

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. You're right I guess, since `sRemoteid` is a JS variable. But depending on its origin, what OP is trying to do might have a better solution.

Comment: Okay, sorry.   via ajax he should execute the `voip_profile_image($visitorid,'thumb'); ` by sending the `sRemoteid` variable in POST or GET, and then change the `img` dom via js

Answer (score -1):

An approach can be that you set a hidden input with an id=something and set its value same as your js variable. Then use $(#something).val () grab the value and run $.ajax to pass that value into your php function.

Comment: My point is that there's no need for a hidden input and a `.val()` call.

Comment: Yes value can be passed directly.